# Environment variables in grpc.AspNet core [GRPC_TRACE, GRPC_VERBOSITY]

Tags: c#, asp.net, grpc, grpc-web

I'm migrating from `grpc.core` to `Grpc.AspNetCore`. I've tried to set enviroment variables to get detailed logs but can't see any difference in the logs. Does Grpc.AspNetCore still uses enviroment variables like `GRPC_TRACE` or `GRPC_VERBOSITY` ([see here the list of env variables](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md#grpc-environment-variables)) for logs? How can I set the verbosity of my logs in `Grpc.AspNetCore`?

For example, I'd like to see logs related to `transport_security,tsi`. I used to do the following in `grpc.core`:

```
$GrpcTrace = "transport_security,tsi"
$GrpcTraceVerbosity = "Debug"
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("GRPC_VERBOSITY", $GrpcTraceVerbosity, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("GRPC_TRACE", $GrpcTrace -join ",", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)
```

I know that `Grpc.AspNetCore` uses `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` for logging, but not sure if this means the env variables are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the guidance provided here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Those variables work for a different project, the C-library with a C# wrapper. That C# library is in maintenance mode.